# Trying to get rid of this random bullet-point

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, post, twitter

So, I added a customized live tweet feature to the website, using something called 'twitter-post-fetcher, and I'm trying to get rid of this random bullet-point next to the live tweet. I tried adding it 'list-style'but that doesn't seem to be working.

[image: []]

Thanks in advance.

```
  <!-- Custom CSS -->
  <link href="css/customstyle.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <style type="text/css">
  .border{
        border-right:1px solid #000;
   }

  footer{
    margin-top: 300px;
  }
  .audio-peri-soc{
    width:190%;
      line-height: 45px;
  }
  .social-media{
    display: block;

  }
  .unstyled{
    list-style-type: none;
  }
    .border{
        border-right:2px solid #ccc;
        height:100px;
    }

    .col-lg-4{
        width:30%;
        list-style-type: none;
      }

      .compress .col-xs-9{
        width: 200%;
        padding-left: none;

      }

      .compress .col-xs-4{
        padding-left:0;
      }
      .compress .col-lg-8 div{
        margin:0;
        padding: 0;
        color:black; 
        font-size: 15px;
        width:100%;   
      }

      .blue{
        color:#fff;
        bottom:0;
        margin-top:-10px;
        margin-left: 10px;
        font-size: 10px;
      }
      .compress{
        width:100%;
        margin: 0;

      }

      .twitter-fav-icon{
        margin-left: 5px;
      }
      .compress p, a {
        font-family:Arial,Sans-Serif;
        font-size:13px;
        color:black;  
        text-decoration:none;
        margin: 0;

      }

      .compress ul li {
        list-style:none;
        overflow:hidden;
        margin:50px;
        padding:5px;
        width:100%;



      }

      #example1{
        margin-left: -40px;
        padding: 0;
        list-style-type: none;

      }
      .interact a{
        margin: 0 0 0 5px;
        padding: 0;
        text-decoration: none;
      }

      .compress ul li:hover {
        background-color:#fff;

      }
      .compress .user, .tweet, .timePosted {
        float:none;
      }
      .compress a, a:visited {
        color:#999; 
      }

      .compress a:hover {
        color:#ccc;
      }

      body{background:url('http://www.placehold.it/1200x800/cccccc/000000') no-repeat center center fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    margin: 0;}

  .effect{
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 10px 100px 0 #000000;
    box-shadow: inset 1px 0 10px #000000;

  }
  .col-md-7 p{
    font-size:15px;
    line-height: 230%;
    text-align: justify;
    width: 500px;
    margin-top: -30px;
}

  #footerSlideButton {
    background-image:url('http://placehold.it/50x50');
    background-repeat:none;
    position: absolute;
    top: -55px;
    right: 20px;
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    border: none;
    cursor: pointer;

  }
.container .pull-left p{
  margin: 0;
  color:blue;
  padding:0;
}


.navbar-fixed-bottom  p{
 margin: 20px;
 font-size: 15px;
}
.navbar-fixed-bottom {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: -20px;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  background-color:#ffffff;   
  padding: 10px 0;
  margin: 0;
}

@media (max-width:630px) {


ul{
  color: blue;
}


}
</style>
</head>

<body>
<footer>
    <div class="container" id="contact" name="contact">
      <div class="row">
      <br>
        <h1 class="centered">THANKS FOR VISITING US</h1>
        <hr>
        <div class="col-lg-4">

            <h3>Latest Tweets
       </h3>


                  <div id="example1"></div>
                  <h4>Watch me on Periscope</h4>
            <script>...</script><a href="#" class="periscope-on-air" data-size="large">...</a> 
        </div><!-- col -->

        <div class="col-lg-4 border">

            <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">

              <div class="form-group">

              </div>

             </form><!-- form -->
          </p>
        </div><!-- col -->

        <div class="col-lg-4">
          <h3> Subscribe
       </h3>


                  <div id="example1"></div>
                     <p>Subscribe for the latest newsletters and updates</p>


<div id="mc_embed_signup" class="mailchimp">

      <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" value="" name="EMAIL" class="required email form-control" id="mce-EMAIL" placeholder="Enter email">
        <input type="submit" value="Subscribe" name="subscribe" id="mc-embedded-subscribe" class="btn btn__bottom--border mailchimp__btn" data-style="shrink" data-horizontal>        
      </div>

        <div id="mce-responses" class="clear">
            <div class="response" id="mce-error-response" style="display:none"></div>
            <div class="response" id="mce-success-response" style="display:none"></div>
            </div>   
            <div class="" style="position: absolute; left: -5000px;"><input type="text" name="..." value=""></div>                          
    </form>
        <span class="form_nospam">No spam</span>  
  </div><!--End mc_embed_signup--> 
        </div><!-- col -->

      </div><!-- row -->

    </div><!-- container -->

<hr class="container">

<div class="container">
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/alwayssunny/?fref=ts" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook fa-2x"></i></a>
                  <a href="https://twitter.com/alwayssunny?ref_src=twsrc%5Egoogle%7Ctwcamp%5Eserp%7Ctwgr%5Eauthor" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter fa-2x"></i></a>
                  <a href="https://soundcloud.com/allisondanger/its-always-sunny-in-philadelphia-intro" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-soundcloud fa-2x"></i></a>

                  <div class="pull-right">
                   <iframe width="60%" height="20" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/226657681&amp;color=999999&amp;auto_play=true&amp;hide_related=false&amp;show_comments=true&amp;show_user=true&amp;show_reposts=false"> </iframe>
                  </div>
                  </div> 

     </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Without even looking at your code, the short answer is almost certainly that you need to strengthen your selector.  The best way to do this is to use your browser's developer tools to determine what style is overriding yours, and make your selector a little bit stronger than that one.

Comment: I'll try that, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want no bullet points at all.

```
* {
  list-style-type: none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I know the asterisk gets rid of all the bullet points, and I don't see myself using them on this site in the future.  It worked great, thanks again!